# Access problem to a control's value in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

i have a problem with accessing a control's value in JavaScript.

```
<tr>
    <th>
        Kullanici Adi:
    </th>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtKullanici" Text="" runat="server" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        Sifre :
    </th>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSifre" Text="" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I can access to txtSifre's text but i can't access to txtKullaniciAdi's text. There is my accessing code:

```
    var Sifre = $("#<%=txtSifre.ClientID %>").val();
    var Kul =  $("#<%=txtKullanici.ClientID %>").val();
```

Do you have any idea?

Çağın

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML, please, rather than the ASP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you setting the TextBox `txtKullanici.Visible=false` in the codebehind?
This would force ASP.NET NOT to render the control which would explain that you can't find it in the html.

If not, show us the html of the textbox control (something like `<input type="text" id="...">`)